# How can I solve to get a large combination of n binary values in Python if memory error occurs?

Tags: python, pandas, memory, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to run get all combination of n binary values 0 and 1.
Here are the codes that I typed.

```
import itertools
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
```

```
combinations=pd.DataFrame(product(range(2),repeat=k))
```

This works when the value of k is small. However, I need to get all combination of at least **30** binary values 0 and 1. For example, I tried `k=31` and it resulted a memory error as shown below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-97fdebdd2a99> in <module>
----> 1 pd.DataFrame(product(range(2),repeat=k))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    467         elif isinstance(data, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(data, (str, bytes)):
    468             if not isinstance(data, (abc.Sequence, ExtensionArray)):
--> 469                 data = list(data)
    470             if len(data) > 0:
    471                 if is_list_like(data[0]) and getattr(data[0], "ndim", 1) == 1:

MemoryError:
```

I have tried to run this piece of codes in a computer with 128GB RAM and a python x64 version yet I was not successful to get the desired results but only memory error.

For example, is it possible to create two or more dataframe that together form my desired dataframe? Nonetheless, I had no ideas on how to work this out to do separate computation getting the combination and combine them at the end.

Or, is there any other way to successfully get the large combination in python?

I could really use your help.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you need a dataframe of that? Why? With repeat=30 you'd be looking at a dataframe of 1,073,741,824 rows.

Comment: @AKX a dataframe is not a must. Yes, and it failed to give the results, but I really need to work to get such a large combination. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what do you need the combinations for in the first place?

Comment: @AKX They are all for calculating probabilities in my field and I need to obtain all the possible binary values combinations.

Comment: @AKX Or is there any other way to get these 0 and 1 combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate all binary strings of N bits (which seems to be what you want here) with a generator like

```
def generate_binary_strings(n):
    format_string = f"{{:0{n}b}}"
    for x in range(1 << n):
        yield format_string.format(x)


for x in generate_binary_strings(4):
    print(x)
```

This outputs

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

I'd still advise against putting them in a list, though - it's going to be long with `bits=30` :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It is very useful and I found I could generate the large combinations with this without the memory error. I will try to work on these results.

Comment: But would you mind if I ask a question? Are these resulted 0 and 1 are str? Because I hope to do multiplication of the probabilities and these 0 and 1.

Comment: They are str, but you could easily map them to integers or whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Hope I can complete the work well!